# AnyLogic Calibration Relative Constraints

Tags: anylogic

I am trying the calibration experiment and need to set constraints for parameters based on each other. Using the constraints tab, it seems that the bound can only be a number and not another parameter.

My exact case is I'm calibrating a triangular distribution, so the minimum cannot be greater than the maximum... Ideally, the constraint should be for example min < max. But this does not seem possible.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opposite to what I said in your previous question I think it's not a good idea to calibrate a triangular distribution... It's better to assume normal distribution and calibrate mean and variance. The thing is that with a triangular distribution in some cases you can't really control the mean so easily because you calibrate it based on min and max.

If you want to calibrate a triangular distribution, make it symmetrical, and use the function triangularAV(average,variability)

If your are completely sure your triangular is NOT symmetrical, consider using a uniform distribution maybe?

Comment: I'm glad you answered this question in relation to the previous one. triangularAV sounds like a good idea. AnyLogic should consider adding relative constraints... Could be useful.